# How to add operator signs '+,-,/,*,mod' etc to a label for making a calculator?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton, calculator

I have made a calculator for simple operations but I cant figure out how should I add the operator signs next to the numerals that I am entering.

I created 2 functions 1 on the number being entered

```
   -(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender
```

and another for the operation

```
-(IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender. 

calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",result];
```

This is for the result to be shown on the label calculatorScreen.

The result i would like would be something like "1+2*3/4" on the calculatorScreen.

Comment: How are you retaining the value that user is tapping on? I mean to say the digits that user is pressing on. Because if you are fetching the value from the calulator screen then you wont be able to perform the operation

Comment: I am fetching the value from the calculator screen on the Digitpress and want to display the value in the Operationpressed method because when the operation like '+' is pressed then it should be displayed . In that case can you suggest something ?

Comment: You can do one this that you can use 2 Label instance on the screen one for the operation and another for the digits and result else when you will fetch the value from the label with the operators appended you wont be able to perform operations without slicing the string into proper values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I misunderstand your question, but what you want is to display on your calculator app the full equation that you've input thus far (e.g. 63+42-62).

Like any other calculator, you should have 2 label, one for your current input, and one to show all that you've entered.(I'm guessing you need the latter)

With the second label up, you can add in the append function into your digitpressed, enter/= function, operation function. If you want to tweak it such 16+23-32 will show up as 
1) 16+23
2) 39-32
3) 39-32=7

then you'll have to add in your own specific code. otherwise the label will input as 16+23-32 = 7

Comment: Thats the whole point , I added a second label but i cant figure out where to append the string.

Comment: It's the same way you append to your first label, from your IBAction method button.

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the character to whatever is already on calculatorScreen. Or you can save the current input in an instance variable and display where appropriate.

This is just a guideline, since I don't know the behavior of your calculator in case of this input: `1 + 2 * 3` (simple calculator will return 9, scientific will return 7).

Comment: Thanx but the main issue is of displaying it in the label . Should I add it in calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",result];

Comment: When user taps on a button, append it to NSMutableString (or clean the NSMutableString, if it is clear button). If you want to display the formula, just change the text of the label to whatever you have stored in NsMutableString.